# Classic report dynamic heading in APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle, dynamic, report, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a classic report driven by a SQL query.

How can I dynamically set column headings, based on the value of another column?

For example, my SQL returns columns `A, B, VERSION`. I'd like the classic report column heading for SQL column `A` to be 'Foo' if `VERSION` is 1, but 'Bar' if `VERSION` is 2.

Comment: What if resultset contains both VERSIONs, 1 and 2? Which heading would you want to have in that case? What if VERSION is neither 1 nor 2?

Comment: The query is constrained by primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you meant by saying that *the query is constrained by primary key*.

Anyway, here's a suggestion which might (or might not) help.

Based on sample SCOTT schema, I created a simple classic report as

```
select e.ename, e.job
from emp e 
where e.deptno = :P42_DEPTNO
```

I also created a `P42_DEPTNO` item which - kind of - *constrains* the result to just one department. For example, if you enter `10` into `P42_DEPTNO`, you'll get employees that work in the ACCOUNTING department.

Furthermore, I created a hidden item `P42_DNAME` whose souce is a SQL query

```
select dname
from dept
where deptno = :P42_DEPTNO
```

and it returns department name for the `P42_DEPTNO` value. Its "Used" property is set to "Always, replacing any existing value in session state". This item (`P42_DNAME`) will be used as a *custom heading* for the `ENAME` column returned by the report.

In order to do that, open `ENAME` column's properties and put this into the "Name" property: `&P42_DNAME.` (literally *ampersand + item name + dot* - don't forget the trailing dot!).

That's all;

- run the report
- enter `10` into `P42_DEPTNO` item
- press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key
- report will display employees that work in department `10`, and `ENAME` column's heading will be `ACCOUNTING`